# what's the printing sequences in c#

Tags: c#-4.0

How can I use a file printing through printer without using default printer in c#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [PrintDocument.Print](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.print.aspx) method and you can specify the name of the printer that you want to use. It can be the default one or any other printer from the system.